# How do I make sure I only have to press enter once and remove the duplicate "press enter to continue..."

Tags: c++, system, registration

In most of the "Press enter to continue.." operation in my code, it seems to make me press on the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key twice for it to continue. I'm not sure what's causing it to display twice instead of once. Here's a sample output of the problem:

```
                  ===============================
                              Main Menu
                  ===============================
                   1. Register for vaccine
                   2. View Profile details
                   3. Sign Out

 Enter your choice: 3
 Signing out...
 Press Enter to continue... Press Enter to continue...
```

I have tried to remove `cin.get()` and `cin.ignore();` but nothing works. Even if the "Press enter to continue..." doesn't display twice, I still have to press enter two times for it to move onto the next function. Please help me fix this. Here's my entire *Vaccine Registration System* code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>
#include<limits> 
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

class User {
public:
    string name, username, password, nationality, add, dob;
    int age, icNumber, ph;
    char sex;
    bool registeredForVaccine;
    
    User() : registeredForVaccine(false) {}

    void displayProfile() const {
        cout << " Name: " << name << "\n Age: " << age << "\n IC Number: " << icNumber
             << "\n Registered for Vaccine: " << (registeredForVaccine ? "YES" : "NO") << "\n";
    }
    
    void saveToFile() const {
        ofstream file("users.txt", ios::app);
        if (file.is_open()) {
            file << username << " " << password << " "
                 << age << " " << dob << " " << sex << " "
                 << icNumber << " " << add << " "
                 << nationality << " " << ph << " "
                 << registeredForVaccine << "\n";
            file.close();
        }
    }

    static bool loadFromFile(const string& username, const string& password, User& user) {
    ifstream file("users.txt");
    string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        istringstream iss(line);
        if (iss >> user.username >> user.password &&
            user.username == username && user.password == password) {
            iss >> user.age >> user.dob >> user.sex
                >> user.icNumber >> user.add
                >> user.nationality >> user.ph
                >> user.registeredForVaccine;

            file.close();
            return true;  // User found in file
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return false;  // User not found in file
    }
};

class VaccineRegistrationSystem {
private:
    vector<User> users;  // Store multiple user accounts
    User currentUser;

public:
    void loginPage(const User& user = User()) {
        cout << " Enter username: ";
        cin >> currentUser.username;

        if (currentUser.username.empty()) {
            return; // Go back to the login/sign-up page
        }

        cout << " Enter password: ";

        // Disable echoing
        char ch;
        string password;
        while ((ch = _getch()) != '\r') { // Enter key pressed
            if (ch == '\b') { // Backspace key pressed
                if (!password.empty()) {
                    cout << "\b \b"; // Move back and overwrite with space
                    password.pop_back(); // Remove last character
                }
            } else {
                cout << '*'; // Print an asterisk
                password.push_back(ch); // Add character to the password
            }
        }

        currentUser.password = password;

        // Enable echoing
        cout << endl;

        // Check user information from file
        User loadedUser;
        if (User::loadFromFile(currentUser.username, currentUser.password, currentUser)) {
            cout << " Login successful!\n";
            mainMenu();
        } else {
            cout << " Invalid username or password. Please try again.\n";
            cout << " Press Enter to continue...";
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cin.get();
            loginPage(); // Show login page again if login fails
        }
    }

    void signUpPage() {
        system("cls");
        cout << " Enter Name: ";
        cin.ignore(); // Clear newline character from the buffer
        getline(cin, currentUser.name);

        cout << " Enter date of birth (xx-xx-xxxx): ";
        cin >> currentUser.dob;

        cout << " Enter IC number: ";
        cin >> currentUser.icNumber;

        cout << " Enter a new username: ";
        cin >> currentUser.username;

        cout << " Enter a new password: ";
        cin >> currentUser.password;

        currentUser.registeredForVaccine = true; // Assuming registration is successful by default
        users.push_back(currentUser);  // Add the new user to the vector
        
        // Save user information to file
        currentUser.saveToFile();
    
        cout << " Registration successful!\n";
        mainMenu();
    }

    void forgotPasswordUsernamePage() {
        system("cls");
        cout << " Enter IC number: ";
        cin >> currentUser.icNumber;
    
        bool foundUser = false;
        for (const User& user : users) {
            if (user.icNumber == currentUser.icNumber) {
                foundUser = true;
                cout << " Found username: " << user.username << "\n and password: " << user.password << "\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    
        if (!foundUser) {
            cout << " IC number is not registered. Press enter again to return to login page...\n";
        }
    }

    void mainMenu() {
    int choice;
    do {
        system("cls");
        cout << setw(50) << " ===============================\n";
        cout << setw(40) << " Main Menu\n";
        cout << setw(50) << " ===============================\n";
        cout << setw(43) << " 1. Register for vaccine\n";
        cout << setw(43) << " 2. View Profile details\n";
        cout << setw(31) << " 3. Sign Out\n";
        cout << setw(5) << "\n Enter your choice: ";

        cin >> choice;
        

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                registerForVaccine();
                break;
            case 2:
                viewProfileDetails();
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << " Signing out...\n";
                break;
            default:
                cout << " Invalid choice. Please try again.\n";
        }
        // Pause for the user to see the output
        cout << " Press Enter to continue...";
    } while (choice != 3);  // Continue the loop until the user chooses to sign out
}

    void registerForVaccine() {
    system("cls");
    cout << " =============================================================\n";
    cout << "                      Register for vaccine\n";
    cout << " =============================================================\n";
    cout << " Enter full name                 : ";
    
    // Clear newline character from the buffer
    cin.ignore();
    
    // Read the full name
    getline(cin, currentUser.name);

    cout << " Enter age                       : ";
    cin >> currentUser.age;

    // Clear the newline character from the buffer after reading the age
    cin.ignore();
    
    cout << " Enter date of birth (xx-xx-xxxx): ";
    cin >> currentUser.dob;
    
    cout << " Enter sex (F/M)                 : ";
    cin >> currentUser.sex;

    cout << " Enter IC Number                 : ";
    cin >> currentUser.icNumber;
    
    cout << " Enter address                   : ";
    cin >> currentUser.add;
 
    cout << " Enter Nationality               : ";
    cin >> currentUser.nationality;

    cout << " Enter phone number              : ";
    cin >> currentUser.ph;
    
    // Check eligibility based on age
    if (currentUser.age >= 18) {
        currentUser.registeredForVaccine = true;
        // Save user information to file after registration
        currentUser.saveToFile();
        // Display registration successful message
        cout << "\n Registration successful!\n";
    } else {
        currentUser.registeredForVaccine = false;
        // Display ineligibility message
        cout << "\n Registration unsuccessful. Eligibility for vaccine is 18 years and above.\n";
    }
        
    // Pause for the user to see the output
    cout << "\n Press Enter to continue...";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}


void viewProfileDetails() {
        system("cls");
        cout << " ===============================\n";
        cout << "    View Profile details\n";
        cout << " ===============================\n";

        if (currentUser.registeredForVaccine) {
            cout << " Full Name     : " << currentUser.name << "\n";
            cout << " Age           : " << currentUser.age << "\n";
            cout << " Date of birth : " << currentUser.dob << "\n";
            cout << " Sex           : " << currentUser.sex << "\n";
            cout << " IC Number     : " << currentUser.icNumber << "\n";
            cout << " Address       : " << currentUser.add << "\n";
            cout << " Nationality   : " << currentUser.nationality << "\n";
            cout << " Phone Number  : " << currentUser.ph << "\n";
        } else {
            cout << " User has not registered for the vaccine. Please register first.\n";
        }

    // Pause for the user to see the output
    cout << "\n Press Enter to continue...";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    }
};
    
int main() {
    VaccineRegistrationSystem registrationSystem;

    do {
        system("cls"); // Use "cls" for Windows
        cout << setw(50) << " ===============================\n";
        cout << setw(41) << " Login/Sign up\n";
        cout << setw(50) << " ===============================\n";
        cout << setw(29) << " 1. Login\n";
        cout << setw(31) << " 2. Sign Up\n";
        cout << setw(48) << " 3. Forgot password/username\n";
        cout << setw(28) << " 4. Exit\n";
        cout << setw(39) << "\n Enter your choice: ";

        int choice;
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                registrationSystem.loginPage();
                break;
            case 2:
                registrationSystem.signUpPage();
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << " Exiting program...\n";
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << " Exiting program.\n";
                return 0; // Exit the program
            default:
                cout << " Invalid choice. Please try again.\n";
        }

        // Pause for the user to see the output
        cout << " Press Enter to continue...";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();

    } while (true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a minor thing but will save you some typing and readability. You don't need to explicitly call `file.close();` if the variable is going out of scope. The destructor will close it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have

```
cin.ignore();
cin.get();
```

The call to `ignore` reads one character. Then the call to `get` reads another character.

So you need to input *at least two* characters (*any* character, not only the newline) for the program to continue.

Comment: Ah i see, it works now but still prompts the "Press enter to continue.." twice instead of once as below :

                  ===============================
                              Main Menu
                  ===============================
                   1. Register for vaccine
                   2. View Profile details
                   3. Sign Out

 Enter your choice: 3
 Signing out...
 Press Enter to continue... Press Enter to continue...

Comment: @user01919191 I would first *peek* at the next character, and if it's already a newline (left by previous input operation) then I'd `ignore()` that. Then print the message and use `ignore()` again to read (and throw away) any character. This works because interactive terminals are line-based and needs the `Enter` key to be pressed for the input to be sent to the program. It's not flawless and allows the user to input more characters (in fact whole essays as long as there's no newline in it), but works well enough.

Comment: @user01919191 After the registration form is done, there's a wait-for-enter inside the registerForVaccine function and another one in main.